# How to calculate SQL percentages based on join of two tables, with only one row showing for each assignment

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I calculate the percentages of those who successfully subscribed? If someone with uID (1 for example) has Not Yet, but then Sub then this is a 100% conversion.

I want to calculate the percentages of each assignmentID group. There can be multiple users in each assignmentID group.

My Query:

```
SELECT assignmentID, 
(SELECT count(assignment) 
FROM group JOIN Subscribed ON group.uID = Subscribed.uID 
WHERE assignment ='test' and status ='Sub') /
(SELECT count(assignment) FROM group JOIN Subscribed ON group.uID = Subscribed.uID) testconversion,

(SELECT count(assignment) 
FROM group JOIN Subscribed ON group.uID = Subscribed.uID 
WHERE assignment ='control' and status ='Sub') /
(SELECT count(assignment) FROM group JOIN Subscribed ON group.uID = Subscribed.uID) controlconversion

FROM group JOIN Subscribed ON group.uID = Subscribed.uID
GROUP BY assignmentID
```

Subscribed

```
uID Status  
1   Not Yet   
1   Sub     
3   Not Yet    
4   Not Yet    
5   Sub
```

Group

```
uID Assignment  AssignmentID
1   test        1
2   test        2
1   control     1
4   test        2
5   test        1
```

Expected Output:

```
AssignmentID   testconversion   controlconversion
1              100%             0%
2              50%              null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a `join` and aggregation:

```
select g.assignmentid,
       (countif(g.assigned = 'test' and s.status = 'sub') /
        nullif(countif(g.assigned = 'test'), 0)
       ) as test_conversion,
       (countif(g.assigned = 'control' and s.status = 'sub') /
        nullif(countif(g.assigned = 'control'), 0)
       ) as control_conversion,
from subscribers s join
     grouped g
     using (uid)
group by g.assignmentid
```